# How to not deploy on save on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 7.2.1 and I use Tomcat for my web application. The problem is everytime I change something and save it redeploys the app, even changes in jsp files, that wouln'd need to compile.

Where can I change this, so it doesn't redeploy on save?

Comment: run it in debug mode?

Comment: Is your webapp packed into a WAR-Archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run tomcat from Netbeans this is a feature. You can see your change immediately after saving.

If you don't want this feature uncheck `Project -> Properties -> Build -> Compiling -> Compile and Save`.

By the way: JPSs are [translated to Servlets and compiled](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahe.html). They are just a layer above Servlets to make live easier for developers.